# Integrate Mobile Vision Barcode API into android app

Tags: android, native, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am developing a BarcodeScanner app on android. Google has release the native Mobile Vision API [link](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/barcodes-overview) for android barcode.So i want to use the android native barcode API instead of any third party library.

So to sum up my problem :

1- How to integrate Barcode API into my Android App?

2- After integrated how to call the barcode function and get back the scan    result ?

Note- A step to step guide will be helpful.

I integrate the code in my app successfully.I posted the answer and question so that it will be helpful to others. If any other ans it would be  appreciated.Thanks in advanced..:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Prerequisite:
•   Android 4.2.2+
•   Latest Android SDK
•   Google Play Services 7.8+ (Rev. 26.0 in SDK)
•   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
•   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8+'
```

Download the code sample code from this [link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision),import the barcode-reader project in android studio. Add the google play services 7.8+ & add the mentioned support library in your app gradle. Now modified the BarcodeTrackerFactory.java and MultiTrackerActivity.java class.

BarcodeTrackerFactory.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.multitracker.ui.camera.GraphicOverlay;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.MultiProcessor;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Tracker;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode;

/**
 * Factory for creating a tracker and associated graphic to be associated with a new barcode.  The
 * multi-processor uses this factory to create barcode trackers as needed -- one for each barcode.
 */
class BarcodeTrackerFactory implements MultiProcessor.Factory<Barcode> {
    public Activity context;
    private GraphicOverlay mGraphicOverlay;


    BarcodeTrackerFactory(GraphicOverlay graphicOverlay) {
        mGraphicOverlay = graphicOverlay;
    }
    BarcodeTrackerFactory(GraphicOverlay graphicOverlay ,Activity ctx) {
        mGraphicOverlay = graphicOverlay;
        this.context =ctx;
    }
    @Override
    public Tracker<Barcode> create(Barcode barcode) {
        BarcodeGraphic graphic = new BarcodeGraphic(mGraphicOverlay,context);
        return new GraphicTracker<>(mGraphicOverlay, graphic);
    }
}

/**
 * Graphic instance for rendering barcode position, size, and ID within an associated graphic
 * overlay view.
 */
class BarcodeGraphic extends TrackedGraphic<Barcode> {
    private static final int COLOR_CHOICES[] = {
            Color.BLUE,
            Color.CYAN,
            Color.GREEN
    };
    private static int mCurrentColorIndex = 0;

    private Paint mRectPaint;
    private Paint mTextPaint;
    private volatile Barcode mBarcode;
    private Activity context;
private boolean isFirstScandetaction=true;
    BarcodeGraphic(GraphicOverlay overlay ,Activity context) {
        super(overlay);
        this.context=context;
        mCurrentColorIndex = (mCurrentColorIndex + 1) % COLOR_CHOICES.length;
        final int selectedColor = COLOR_CHOICES[mCurrentColorIndex];

        mRectPaint = new Paint();
        mRectPaint.setColor(selectedColor);
        mRectPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mRectPaint.setStrokeWidth(4.0f);

        mTextPaint = new Paint();
        mTextPaint.setColor(selectedColor);
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(36.0f);
    }

    /**
     * Updates the barcode instance from the detection of the most recent frame.  Invalidates the
     * relevant portions of the overlay to trigger a redraw.
     */
    void updateItem(Barcode barcode) {
        mBarcode = barcode;
        if (isFirstScandetaction) {
            postInvalidate();
            if (null != mBarcode) {
                isFirstScandetaction = false;

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_RESULT", barcode.rawValue.toString());
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT",String.valueOf( barcode.format));
                 context.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
                 context.finish();
            }

        }
    }

    /**
     * Draws the barcode annotations for position, size, and raw value on the supplied canvas.
     */
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        Barcode barcode = mBarcode;
        if (barcode == null) {
            return;
        }

        // Draws the bounding box around the barcode.
        RectF rect = new RectF(barcode.getBoundingBox());
        rect.left = translateX(rect.left);
        rect.top = translateY(rect.top);
        rect.right = translateX(rect.right);
        rect.bottom = translateY(rect.bottom);
        canvas.drawRect(rect, mRectPaint);

        // Draws a label at the bottom of the barcode indicate the barcode value that was detected.
        canvas.drawText(barcode.rawValue, rect.left, rect.bottom, mTextPaint);

        Log.v("On Draw", "called");
    }
}
```

MultiTrackerActivity.java

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.multitracker.ui.camera.CameraSourcePreview;
import com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.multitracker.ui.camera.GraphicOverlay;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.MultiProcessor;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector;

/**
 * Activity for the multi-tracker app.  This app detects faces and barcodes with the rear facing
 * camera, and draws overlay graphics to indicate the position, size, and ID of each face and
 * barcode.
 */
public final class MultiTrackerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MultiTracker";

    private static final int RC_HANDLE_GMS = 9001;
    // permission request codes need to be < 256
    private static final int RC_HANDLE_CAMERA_PERM = 2;

    private CameraSource mCameraSource = null;
    private CameraSourcePreview mPreview;
    private GraphicOverlay mGraphicOverlay;

    /**
     * Initializes the UI and creates the detector pipeline.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mPreview = (CameraSourcePreview) findViewById(R.id.preview);
        mGraphicOverlay = (GraphicOverlay) findViewById(R.id.faceOverlay);

        // Check for the camera permission before accessing the camera.  If the
        // permission is not granted yet, request permission.
        int rc = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        if (rc == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            createCameraSource();
        } else {
            requestCameraPermission();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the requesting of the camera permission.  This includes
     * showing a "Snackbar" message of why the permission is needed then
     * sending the request.
     */
    private void requestCameraPermission() {
        Log.w(TAG, "Camera permission is not granted. Requesting permission");

        final String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA};

        if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, RC_HANDLE_CAMERA_PERM);
            return;
        }

        final Activity thisActivity = this;

        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity, permissions,
                        RC_HANDLE_CAMERA_PERM);
            }
        };

        Snackbar.make(mGraphicOverlay, R.string.permission_camera_rationale,
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction(R.string.ok, listener)
                .show();
    }



    /**
     * Creates and starts the camera.  Note that this uses a higher resolution in comparison
     * to other detection examples to enable the barcode detector to detect small barcodes
     * at long distances.
     */
    private void createCameraSource() {


        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        // A barcode detector is created to track barcodes.  An associated multi-processor instance
        // is set to receive the barcode detection results, track the barcodes, and maintain
        // graphics for each barcode on screen.  The factory is used by the multi-processor to
        // create a separate tracker instance for each barcode.      
        BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(context).build();
        BarcodeTrackerFactory barcodeFactory = new BarcodeTrackerFactory(mGraphicOverlay,this);
        barcodeDetector.setProcessor(
                new MultiProcessor.Builder<>(barcodeFactory).build());


        if (!barcodeDetector.isOperational()) {
            // Note: The first time that an app using the barcode or face API is installed on a
            // device, GMS will download a native libraries to the device in order to do detection.
            // Usually this completes before the app is run for the first time.  But if that
            // download has not yet completed, then the above call will not detect any barcodes
            // and/or faces.
            //
            // isOperational() can be used to check if the required native libraries are currently
            // available.  The detectors will automatically become operational once the library
            // downloads complete on device.
            Log.w(TAG, "Detector dependencies are not yet available.");
        }

        // Creates and starts the camera.  Note that this uses a higher resolution in comparison
        // to other detection examples to enable the barcode detector to detect small barcodes
        // at long distances.
        mCameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(getApplicationContext(), barcodeDetector)
                .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(1600, 1024)
                .setRequestedFps(15.0f)
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Restarts the camera.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        startCameraSource();
    }

    /**
     * Stops the camera.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mPreview.stop();
    }

    /**
     * Releases the resources associated with the camera source, the associated detectors, and the
     * rest of the processing pipeline.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mCameraSource != null) {
            mCameraSource.release();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Callback for the result from requesting permissions. This method
     * is invoked for every call on {@link #requestPermissions(String[], int)}.
     * <p>
     * <strong>Note:</strong> It is possible that the permissions request interaction
     * with the user is interrupted. In this case you will receive empty permissions
     * and results arrays which should be treated as a cancellation.
     * </p>
     *
     * @param requestCode  The request code passed in {@link #requestPermissions(String[], int)}.
     * @param permissions  The requested permissions. Never null.
     * @param grantResults The grant results for the corresponding permissions
     *                     which is either {@link PackageManager#PERMISSION_GRANTED}
     *                     or {@link PackageManager#PERMISSION_DENIED}. Never null.
     * @see #requestPermissions(String[], int)
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode != RC_HANDLE_CAMERA_PERM) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Got unexpected permission result: " + requestCode);
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            return;
        }

        if (grantResults.length != 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Camera permission granted - initialize the camera source");
            // we have permission, so create the camerasource
            createCameraSource();
            return;
        }

        Log.e(TAG, "Permission not granted: results len = " + grantResults.length +
                " Result code = " + (grantResults.length > 0 ? grantResults[0] : "(empty)"));

        DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                finish();
            }
        };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Multitracker sample")
                .setMessage(R.string.no_camera_permission)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, listener)
                .show();
    }
    /**
     * Starts or restarts the camera source, if it exists.  If the camera source doesn't exist yet
     * (e.g., because onResume was called before the camera source was created), this will be called
     * again when the camera source is created.
     */
    private void startCameraSource() {

        // check that the device has play services available.
        int code = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(
                getApplicationContext());
        if (code != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            Dialog dlg =
                    GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, code, RC_HANDLE_GMS);
            dlg.show();
        }

        if (mCameraSource != null) {
            try {
                mPreview.start(mCameraSource, mGraphicOverlay);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to start camera source.", e);
                mCameraSource.release();
                mCameraSource = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now to call the scan code and recieve the result-
BarCodeReader.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BarCodeReader extends FragmentActivity {

    String QR_CODE = "256";
    private Button btnscan;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.scanlayout);
        btnscan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scanbtn);

        btnscan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(BarCodeReader.this,
                        MultiTrackerActivity.class);

                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
                if (format.equals(QR_CODE)) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            BarCodeReader.this,
                            "content is : " + contents + " \n Format is:    "
                                    + format, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(BarCodeReader.this, "wrong format",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // To Handle cancel
                Log.i("App", "Scan unsuccessful");
            }
        }
    }

}
```